# Android forward abstract domain socket to a port number in java

Tags: java, android, sockets, networking

I would like to forward abstract domain socket to a port number in Android with a java application.

One hacky way to do it is to use adb to forward the domain socket to a host port and then reverse it back to a port on the device. e.g.

```
adb forward tcp:8080 localabstract:[abstract namespace]
adb reverse tcp:8080 tcp:8080
```

However, is there a way to set up some kind of local socket server locally with an activity to accomplish this?